# Ubuntu Server - modprobe cdc_ether module not found :(

Tags: networking, drivers, server, usb-modem

So I'm trying to install a usb dongle on the server.
However, when doing modpropbe cdc_ether I'm getting no module found.

It seems the usb networking driver stack is missing in this installation.

Could I please ask that someone point me to:

A) how to find the driver stack that contains cdc_ether

B) A reference to driver installation guide perhaps.

My google searches are not yielding good enough info for someone like with with limited experience in linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually this module is located in `linux-image-extra-\`uname -r\``, make sure you have installed it.

Comment: This really helped me find instructions, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this module is located in

```
 linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

Make sure you have installed it.

Comment: This worked, after installing the linux image extras, I had the cdc_ether module available and enabled!